# React Render Props

Tags: reactjs

This is my code implementing Render Props pattern with a simple example: `injecting toggle` method into any button passed into the above pattern.

```
function App() {
    return (
        <WrapperComponent
             render={(toggle)=><button onClick={toggle}>Toggled button</button>}
        />
  );
}

const maker= (props)=> {
    const toggle = () => console.log('Success');
    return toggle;
};

const WrapperComponent = (props) => props.render(maker(props))
```

***However, what I want to achieve is to change toggle method such as forcing some styling change for the button e.g. change background color. How may I achieve that in a React way?***

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can provide className or styles to the button:

```js
const maker = (props) => {
    const toggle = () => console.log('Success');
    return { toggle, className: "redButton" }
};

<WrapperComponent
  render={({ toggle, className, ref })=><button ref={ref} onClick={toggle} className={className}>Toggled button</button>}
/>
```

Ref:

```js
const WrapperComponent = (props) => {
  const ref = useRef();

  const toggle = () => console.log('Success');

  props.render({ ref, className: "redButton", toggle })
}
```

Also you should probably avoid render props pattern in favor of hooks, unless you can't use hooks.

Comment: That does the job. Actually, what I want is to access the DOM button element inside maker method. How can I do that?

Comment: You need to pass ref

Comment: Can I do that keeping <App/> generic? I mean not to have ref inside App. Only inside WrapperComponent and maker. Is that possible? If yes how?

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: Do not think the above works. `ref.current` is undefined. I want to access DOM button from inside WrapperComponent